# Current primary key is ineffective at preventing duplicates. Does this sound like a good way to rearchitect my tables?

Tags: sql

Every so often, I update our research recruitment database with those who responded to our Craigslist ad. Each respondent is given a unique `respondentID`, which is the primary key.

Sometimes, people respond to these Craigslist ads multiple times. I think we may have duplicate people in our database, which is bad.

I would like to change the primary key of all my recruitment tables from `respondentID` to `Email`, which will prevent duplicates and make it easier to look up information. There are probably duplicate email records in my database already, and I need to clean this up if so.

Here's the current architecture for my three recruitment tables:

1. demographic - contains columns like `RespondentID (PK)`, `Email` (I want this to be PK), `Phone`, etc
2. genre - contains columns like `RespondentID (PK)`, `Horror`, etc
3. platform - contains columns like `RespondentID (PK)`, `TV`, etc.

I want to join all three tables together at some point so we can get a better understanding of someone.

Here are my questions:

1. How can I eliminate duplicate respondents already in my database? (I can tell if they are duplicates because they will have the same Email value.)
2. Given my current architecture, how can I transition my database to have Email as the primary key without messing up my data?
3. After transitioning to a new architecture, what is the process I can use to delete duplicates in my Craigslist ad spreadsheet before I append them to Demo, Genre, and Platform tables?

Here are my ideas about solutions:

1. Create backup tables. Join the three tables and export the big table to Excel. In Excel, use Data Filtering and Conditional Formatting to find the duplicate entries, and delete them by hand. Unfortunately, I have 20,000 records which will crash Excel. :( The chief issue is that I don't know how to remove duplicate entries within a table using SQL. (Also, if I have two entries by bobdole@republican.com, one entry should remain.) Can you come up with a smarter solution involving SQL and Access?
2. After each Email record is unique, I will create new tables with each using Email as the primary key.
3. When I want to remove duplicates within the data I'd like to import, I should be able to easily do it within Excel. Next, I will use this SQL command to deduplicate between the current database and the incoming data:

   ```
   DELETE * from newParticipantsList
   WHERE Email in (SelectEmail from Demo)
   ```

I'm going to try to duplicate my current architecture in a small test table in Access and see if I can figure it out. Overall, I don't have much experience with joining tables and removing data in SQL, so it's a little scary.

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure your data is well and truly backed up first :P

Comment: Have you ever thought about leaving the architecture as is, and just creating a `UNIQUE INDEX` on the `EMail` column? That would prevent duplicates, too! (without all the re-architecting...)

Comment: Marc: My three tables (even though they should be one-to-one) have different numbers of records. I think this may have happened from inputting data into one table and not the others, but I'm not completely sure. :/

Is the unique_index like a record number? I'm not sure that would work if I have a different number of records in each table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm just being thick, but why don't you just create a new Identity column in the existing table?  You can always remove those records you deem duplicates, but the Identity column is guaranteed to be unique under all circumstances.

It will be up to you to make sure that any new records inserted into the table are not duplicates, by checking the Email column.

Comment: Based on a search I did, I assume that "Identity" column means a field where each record is a unique value. (The first record might have "1" in that field, the second will have "2", etc. Each will be unique.)

How do I make sure that, when I create identity columns in the other two tables, that the keys correspond to the right records? I have a problem where the three tables have different numbers of records. This may have been from inserting new records into one table and not the other because of incomplete info & inexperience.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Numbers are not reused; if a record gets deleted after it is assigned a number, that number just goes missing.

Comment: Sorry, my above comment was posted prematurely. I just added to it, and then saw your answer after publishing it. Does your answer still apply to my edited comment?

Comment: Ah, yes, your right; you'll still have to write Foreign Keys to your associated tables that correspond to the new Primary Keys in the Identity column.  It can be done; it just takes a bit of creative query writing, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicates from demographic table you could do something like:

```
WITH RecordsToKeep AS (
SELECT  MIN(RespondentID) as RespondentID
    FROM    demographic 
GROUP BY Email 
) DELETE  demographic
FROM        demographic
LEFT JOIN   RecordsToKeep on RecordsToKeep.RespondentID = demographic.RespondentID
where   RecordsToKeep.RespondentID IS NULL
```

This will keep the first record for each email address and delete the rest. You will need to remap the genre and platform tables before you delete the source.

In terms of what to do in the future, you could get SQL to do all the de-duplicating for you by importing the data into a staging table and then only import distinct records to the final when the address isn't already in the demographic table.

There is no reason to change the Email Address to be the primary key. String's aren't great primary keys for a number of reasons. The problem you have isn't with duplicate keys, the problem is how you are inserting the data.